# Ansbile Cron Support for CRON_TZ

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I can't seem to find support for the CRON_TZ settings for crontab.  How would I configure ansible to run a cron job for a specific timezone?

This is what I want my crontab file to look like.  This cron config is currently running on a CentOS 7 box.

/etc/crontab:

```
# Default Timezone
30 9 * * * bobr /home/bobr/crontest.sh LOCAL "`date -R`"

CRON_TZ=Canada/Eastern
30 11 * * * bobr /home/bobr/crontest.sh Eastern "`date -R`"
45 11 * * * bobr/home/bobr/crontest.sh Eastern "`date -R`"

CRON_TZ=Canada/Pacific
30 8 * * * bobr/home/bobr/crontest.sh Pacific "`date -R`"
44 8 * * * bobr/home/bobr/crontest.sh Pacific "`date -R`"
```

For reference crontest.sh just sends an email with the 2 parameters:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "this is the cron test. $1 $2" | mail -s "Cron Test" bobr@example.com
```

Comment: I submitted a feature request here: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/64393

Answer (score 0):

Didnt find any attribute for timezone set in ansible [CRON](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/cron_module.html) module.. May be you can try out other way.. using shell..

```
- name: configure cron using shell
  shell:  crontab cron.conf
```

and conf file is

```
cat cron.conf
# Default Timezone
30 9 * * * bobr /home/bobr/crontest.sh LOCAL "`date -R`"

CRON_TZ=Canada/Eastern
30 11 * * * bobr /home/bobr/crontest.sh Eastern "`date -R`"
45 11 * * * bobr/home/bobr/crontest.sh Eastern "`date -R`"

CRON_TZ=Canada/Pacific
30 8 * * * bobr/home/bobr/crontest.sh Pacific "`date -R`"
44 8 * * * bobr/home/bobr/crontest.sh Pacific "`date -R`"
```

Comment: Thank you.  I thought about that but was trying to find a more proper way to do this.  I may end up just doing a template.